# Self attention module occpuying too large VRAM with large input

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I was trying to add a self-attention module for Progressive GAN (ProGAN) and put it to the last layer before to RGB. After running a simple test file I found that when the model grows to 256x256 output, the process is killed.

Then I tried the following test code:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels):
        super(SelfAttention, self).__init__()
        self.channels = channels
        num_heads = 4
        self.mha = nn.MultiheadAttention(channels, num_heads, batch_first=True)
        self.ln = nn.LayerNorm([channels])
        self.ff_self = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LayerNorm([channels]),
            nn.Linear(channels, channels),
            nn.GELU(),
            nn.Linear(channels, channels)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        size = x.shape[3]
        print("SIZE", size)
        print("CHANNELS", self.channels)
        x = x.view(-1, self.channels, size * size).swapaxes(1, 2)
        print()
        x_ln = self.ln(x)
        attention_value, _ = self.mha(x_ln, x_ln, x_ln)
        attention_value = attention_value + x
        attention_value = self.ff_self(attention_value) + attention_value
        return attention_value.swapaxes(2, 1).view(-1, self.channels, size, size)


class SelfAttention2(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels):
        super(SelfAttention2, self).__init__()
        self.query = nn.Conv2d(channels, channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.key = nn.Conv2d(channels, channels // 8, kernel_size=1)
        self.value = nn.Conv2d(channels, channels, kernel_size=1)
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=-1)

    def forward(self, x):
        N, C, H, W = x.size()
        query = self.query(x).view(N, -1, W*H).permute(0, 2, 1) # (N, C, H*W)
        key = self.key(x).view(N, -1, W*H) # (N, C, H*W)
        energy = torch.bmm(query, key) # (N, H*W, H*W)
        attention = self.softmax(energy)
        value = self.value(x).view(N, -1, W*H) # (N, C, H*W)
        out = torch.bmm(value, attention.permute(0, 2, 1))
        out = out.view(N, C, H, W)
        return out


if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    x = torch.randn((1, 64, 256, 256))
    
    sa1 = SelfAttention(64)
    sa1(x)

    sa2 = SelfAttention2(64)
    sa2(x)
```

Neither module worked for trying to allocate 16G VRAM. (With this one module take up 16G I cannot even run the whole model in 3090)

And I am told explictly that the method itself, i.e. "Add attention to ProGAN or StyleGAN" will work and has been done.

So, is my understanding of the idea is false or the implementation has flaw?

Also, I have train the model to 32x32 and it worked ok.

Suggentions upon my understanding or my coding.

Comment: Could you maybe check the number of parameters using summary() from torchsummary import summary?

Comment: @Mariusmarten I know the number of parameters is huge, while I wanted to ask what is the correct way to do this "Attention in ProGAN" stuff.